# Cannot remove on mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi im trying to simply remove a document from a collection using mongoose but for some strange reason I cannot get it to work.

Here is the code:

```
 function deleteUserevent()
{console.log('in delete User Event');

    models.Userevent.remove({ _id: "5214f4050acb53fe31000004"}, function(err) {
    if (!err){
           console.log('deleted user event!');
    }
    else {
           console.log('error');
    }

});
}
```

Can anyone help me out on my syntax? I know the _id is stored as new ObjectId("5214f4050acb53fe31000004") but I have tried this with no joy?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens instead? Does it print "error" or does it printed "deleted user event" without deleting, or does it print nothing at all, or does it print a call trace?

Answer (score 1):

In MongoDB, the "_id" field of documents is of type ObjectId, as you mentioned.  This is not equal to a String, so running the query

```
db.userevent.remove({ _id: "5214f4050acb53fe31000004"});
```

will not match anything, and will not remove anything.  Instead, you must search for a document where the _id field is an ObjectId with that value:

```
db.userevents.remove({ _id: ObjectId("5214f4050acb53fe31000004")});
```

In mongoose, you can use the findByIdAndRemove command to remove a document with a specific _id.  This command takes either an ObjectId or a String as an argument, so

```
query = Userevent.findByIdAndRemove("5214f4050acb53fe31000004");
```

should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `exec()` after query.

It should work like this:

```
await models.Userevent.findByIdAndDelete("5214f4050acb53fe31000004").exec()
```